# iPhone MP3 Streaming alternative to Segmenting

Tags: iphone

I have run into a bit of a problem.  I built an iPhone app that streams my podcasts via the MPMoviePlayerController.  Apple will not approve it because it can use too much bandwidth over the Carrier Network.  So their workaround is to use a Stream Segmenter.  I am unable to install a stream segmenter on my server.  Are their ANY other solutions people have come up with that can help me stream my podcast to iPhone devices?  Even if I have to make it a Web Application as opposed to a native application.

Thanks,

John

Comment: have u tried using apple stream segmenter?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple service like Encoding.com to create iphone segmented ondemand versions of your files for multi bitrate adaptive playback. You could also provide a high and low quality and only display the high when the reachability class shows that your using wifi. I had to do the second option to get one of my apps to pass approval. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't want a native app, I think you can just put a video link on a webpage and when the user clicks it Quicktime will take over and play the file.  It will play the file as it downloads it.

I don't have any experience streaming large files over the iPhone, so I can't help guide you on alternatives and keeping it a native app.

Comment: You know whats weird is that I can goto the podcast web site, click on an MP3 link and it will play in the QuickTime player on the carrier network.  I don't understand how that will work fine, but when I open that same link in my native app using MPMoviePlayer(which seems to be essentially the QuickTime player), Apple says I'm tying up too much bandwidth.  Just bizarre

Comment: @postalservice14: None of the App Store rules apply for Apple's apps.

Of course, then you could bring up the point that all the web browsers in the App Store can access it too.

But nobody said logic was involved.